# How to list objects in a template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to list some objects that I already have in a Service, but they don't appear when I load the localhost. Here are the code:

item.model.ts

```
export class Item {
  status: string = 'started';
  constructor(public title: string = ''){}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { Item }   from './app.model';
import { AppService }from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
   <div>
     <form (submit)="onSubmit()">
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.title" name="title">
     </form>
     <app-list></app-list>
   </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent{
 item: Item = new Item();

 constructor(public appService: AppService){
 }

 onSubmit(){
  this.appService.todos.push(this.item);
  console.log('return: ' + this.appService.todos);
  this.item = new Item();
 }

}
```

app-list.component.ts

**In this component i tried to list the itens as you can see in the HTML.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService }from './app.service';

import { Item } from './app.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: 
  `
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">
    <span>{{todo.title}}</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  `
})

export class AppList implements OnInit {
 todo: Item[];

 constructor(private appService: AppService){}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  let todos = this.appService.todos;
  console.log('todos: ' + todos);
 }

}
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Item }       from './app.model';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    todos = [
        {'id' : 1, 'description': "test item 1"},
        {'id' : 2, 'description': "test item 2"}
    ];
}
```

When I add a new item, nothing appears to me, but the console shows:

`todos: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: You know your `todos` don't have a `title` field right?

Comment: There is no todos property on `AppList` class. Do you have any IDE? I see a lot of problems

Comment: 1) Make sure your item type have id and title. 2) The `AppService` have todos but dont have title property they have description. 3) you app list component dont have todos it hav todo. 4) create the todos variable global in AppList component.

Comment: Thanks @BarbarBilal, i'll try your tips. I'm starting in this world, so yeah... I know that have a lot of problems. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BarbarBilal i found the errors and I'm posting here to you guys see. Everything is working as I would like.

First, the model:

```
export class Item {
 constructor(public title: string = ''){}
}
```

Then, the AppComponent:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { Item }   from './app.model';
import { AppService }from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
   <div>
  <form (submit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.title" name="title">
  </form>
  <app-list></app-list>
 </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent{

 item: Item = new Item();

 constructor(public appService: AppService){
 }

 onSubmit(){
  this.appService.todos.push(this.item);
  console.log('return: ' + this.appService.todos[0].title);
  this.item = new Item();
 }

}
```

The AppList:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService }from './app.service';

import { Item } from './app.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: 
  `
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">
    {{todo.title}}
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  `
})

export class AppList implements OnInit{

 todos: Item[];

 constructor(private appService: AppService){}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.todos = this.appService.todos;
  console.log('todos: ' + this.todos[0].title);
 }
}
```

Finally, the AppService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Item }       from './app.model';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    todos = [
        {title : 'test item 1'}
    ];

}
```

As you can see, the AppService now have *todos* and have *title* property. The app list component now have *todos*. And I create the *todos* variable global in AppList component.